# Binding interceptor in grpc-web Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, grpc-web

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-web-interceptor/ to add interceptor for my grpc-web client requests. Using the final line that explains how to bind an interceptor to a call, using that call in typescript I firstly get an error because the protoc-gen compiler creates a client service with the following arguments in the constructor

```
constructor (hostname: string,
             credentials?: null | { [index: string]: string; },
             options?: null | { [index: string]: string; })
```

so I cannot really use the fromat explained in the tutorial which is this

```
const promiseClient = new MyServicePromiseClient(
    host, creds, {'unaryInterceptors': [interceptor1, interceptor2, interceptor3]});
```

I tried using a similar format like this

```
const promiseClient = new MyServicePromiseClient(
    host, creds, {'unaryInterceptors': 'interceptor1'});
```

but it does not work, I have breakpoints in my interceptor, and they never reach that point.
How can I bind my interceptor to the call?

**EDIT**

My interceptor code is not something fancy, it's just the code from the tutorial, somewhat converted to Typescript but here it is

```
export class interceptor1 {

intercept = function (request: any, invoker: any) {
    // Update the request message before the RPC.
    const reqMsg = request.getRequestMessage();
    reqMsg.setMessage('[Intercept request]' + reqMsg.getMessage());
    // After the RPC returns successfully, update the response.
    return invoker(request).then((response: any) => {
        // You can also do something with response metadata here.
        console.log(response.getMetadata());
    });
}
```

}

Comment: can you please improve the example if you used class name string or the class as interceptor.

Comment: @vedantsali I am not sure I follow what you are requesting

Comment: -  `{'unaryInterceptors': 'interceptor1'}`   interceptor1 should not be a string. It should be a method. the quotes are confusing

Comment: well, it was ok 2 years ago......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out this is was a specific issue in grpc-web up to version **1.2.0**

Workaround for specific version is to use @ts-ignore and interceptors will work

From grpc-web version **1.2.1** and later, the issue has been fixed

Comment: it should be released now

Comment: @dmaixner Thanks, I updated my answer and my node modules